# I need the name of a horror movie about a winged demon/boy hybrid

Tags: story-identification, demons

The hybrid, along with his normal sister who has the ability to control and restrain him are being moved to a more secure location. They have both been in custody for a hundred years or so. The demon hybrid causes those around him to hallucinate. He has his wings clipped to curtail his power. Naturally, he gets loose and at one point rips a man into two pieces. The man's lower half continues to walk off.

Comment: What else can you remember about this film? When did you see it, what language was it in, how old was it? Any idea what any of the characters looked like?

Comment: Could this be [Dark Haul](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3188614/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) ? The sister in that was only half-human though... but they've been captive for a while and there's certainly carnage and a beast that escapes (as such - he was more "let out")... [YouTube Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGndT09Vwfo)

Comment: @JonClements it is indeed that movie, with those"walking legs" scene, please post the answer.